# Automate the deployment of a .war application on a Payara-Full Pod in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, war, payara

As the title says, I need to automate the deployment of an application running on a Payara-Full Pod.

For now I've manually deployed the .war file by copying it inside the Pod (through the `kubectl cp` command), and then logging inside the pod console through `kubectl exec --stdin --tty <pod-name> -- /bin/bash`.

Once I'm logged in, I access the Payara console by running the command `asadmin` and logging in, and then I manually deploy the .war through `deploy <filename>.war`.

How can I automate this process?

I thought of using a custom Payara image or an InitContainer, but I don't know what is the best practice for this type of deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merely copy your .war to payara autodeploy directory inside container (`${PAYARA_HOME}/glassfish/domins/[domain you use]/autodeploy`) and restart service. You web-app will be deployed automatically on domain restart.

Comment: I've built a custom image with a Dockerfile that copies my .war into the $DEPLOY_DIR.
That fixes my problem, as Payara-Full now autodeploys my application on startup.

Thanks anyway for the help :)